# Look up and copy data against one value which has values against multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]If you look at attached impact, sheet 1 has multiple links in a column and this links have multiple values against them in different columns.

In my use case, there might be few links which are exactly same in different rows but have unique values against them in those different rows. I want the links along with all values against them which show 'Active' against them to be sorted and displayed in another sheet.

Example, in the image, under sheet 1, there are 6 rows which show 'Active' under column Q.

Out of all these, row 2 and 9 have the same url links which I am showing in the Sheet 2 and the values showing against it are the ones which which are combination of values against it in sheet 1 in row 2 and 9

Same applies to row 5 and 13

There are also links which are in only one row example, row 7

Now sure how a formula can be written to get this data. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula in `V2`:

```vb
=TOROW(FILTER(B2:I13,(Q2:Q13=U2)*(P2:P13="active"),""),1,FALSE)
```

It filters yours data by URL and Activate-status - and then writes the results into one row.

Comment: Hey @Ike Thanks for your inputs. unfortunately I do not see =torow function on my excel. May be I do not have Excel 365. Any other way I can get this?